# What do _T and L mean in C++ and how can I pass them?

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a keylogger in C++. 
Part of my keylogger is to capture the screen.
After a lot of searching, I decided to try to understand how it works instantly by trying to build one.

This is my screen capture code:

```
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL); // get the desktop device context
    HDC hDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // create a device context to use yourself

    // get the height and width of the screen
    int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);

    // create a bitmap
    HBITMAP hbDesktop = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);

    // use the previously created device context with the bitmap
    SelectObject(hDest, hbDesktop);

    // copy from the desktop device context to the bitmap device context
    // call this once per 'frame'
    BitBlt(hDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    /*CImage image; // from this code i tried to understand how to save the bitmap
    image.Attach(hbDesktop); 
    image.Save(pathname, Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);*/

    CImage image;//this code is what I came up with eventually
    image.Attach(hbDesktop);
    CHAR buffer[100] = _T("this is a literal string");  // THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM STARTS 
    sprintf(buffer,_T("this is a literal string"), 1);
    image.Save(_T(buffer), Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
```

I tried to make the program save the bitmap file each time with a different name. 
The problem is that the last line doesn't work unless I use `_T` sign, and when I do put the `_T`, it won't take the buffer and says "identifier "Lbuffer" is undefined". What does this mean? Where do I need to put this L sign and why?
Also, is there a better way to save bitmap to a file without using this `_T` sign?

I've tried to look this up, and on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf.aspx they say this is about Unicode. Why do I need Unicode for this function?

Comment: Sorry, even after reading the link still I did not understand the subject
I'd be happy if someone could explain to me with an example of the code  I brought 
Thank you very much to assistants

Answer (score 17):

`_T()`, and its Win32 equivilent `TEXT()`, are **preprocessor macros** that prepend the input value with `L` if `_UNICODE` or `UNICODE` are defined, respectively.

These macros are meant to be used with **character/string literals only**.  You *cannot* use them with variables.  So `_T(buffer)` is not valid code.  That is why you are getting an `identifer "Lbuffer" not defined` error (`_UNICODE` is obviously defined in your project).

If `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE` are defined, `_T("literal")` and `TEXT("literal")` are evaluated by the compiler as `L"literal"` - a **wide string literal of type `wchar_t[]`**.

If `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE` are not defined, `_T("literal")` and `TEXT("literal")` are evaluated by the compiler as `"literal"` - a **narrow string literal of type `char[]`**.

`CHAR` is not a macro, it is a **typedef** for `char`, and is unconditional (there is an equivalent `WCHAR` typedef for `wchar_t`).

Thus, this line:

```
CHAR buffer[100] = _T("this is a literal string");
```

Is evaluated as this:

```
// when _UNICODE is defined
char buffer[100] = L"this is a literal string"; // DOES NOT COMPILE!
// You cannot assign/fill a char[] array with wchar_t data!
```

```
// when _UNICODE is not defined
char buffer[100] = "this is a literal string"; // OK
```

If you want to use `_T()`/`TEXT()`, you must use `_TCHAR`/`TCHAR` instead of `CHAR` so they match:

```
_TCHAR buffer[100] = _T("this is a literal string");
```

`_TCHAR`/`TCHAR` are `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE`-sensitive preprocessor `#define`s.  When `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE` are defined, they resolve to `wchar_t`, otherwise they resolve to `char` instead:

```
// when _UNICODE is defined
wchar_t buffer[100] = L"this is a literal string"; // OK
```

```
// when _UNICODE is not defined
char buffer[100] = "this is a literal string"; // OK
```

[`sprint()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx) only works with `char` data.  The `wchar_t` version is `swprintf()`, and the `_TCHAR`/`TCHAR` version is `_stprintf()`:

```
char buffer[100];
sprintf(buffer, "this is a literal string", 1); // OK
```

```
wchar_t buffer[100];
swprintf(buffer, L"this is a literal string", 1); // OK
```

```
_TCHAR buffer[100];
_stprintf(buffer, _T("this is a literal string"), 1); // OK
```

[`CImage::Save()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06f3fhw.aspx) accepts a `LPCTSTR` as input.  `LPCTSTR` is a **typedef** for `const TCHAR*`, thus resolves to `const wchar_t*` when `UNICODE` is defined, otherwise resolves to `const char*`.  As it is `UNICODE`-sensitive, but your `buffer` is always a `char[]`, you will not be able to pass `buffer` to `Save()` if `UNICODE` is defined.  You need to use `TCHAR` instead:

```
// In this case, you should use the Win32 macros instead of the C macros.
// It is not good practice to mix C's _T()/_TCHAR macros with Win32 APIs,
// and Win32's TEXT()/TCHAR macros with C APIs, though technically it will
// work fine.  Best to keep the two APIs separate...

TCHAR buffer[100];
_stprintf(buffer, TEXT("filename_%d.bmp"), 1);
image.Save(buffer, Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);
```

Comment: good answer, had to read it twice or thrice but good nonetheless